# Can't automount partition that contain the booting iso file

Tags: boot, iso-image, grub2, udev

I have a strange problem

i am dual booting windows with chromeos from iso file using grub2

i am using the following udev rules

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="block", ATTRS{removable}=="0", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1" ,
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="0"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="mmc", ATTRS{type}!="MMC", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="0"
```

all the partition get mounted except the one with the iso file

what is going wrong ?